# How to change variable from if loop to global?

Tags: python, flask, post, request, global-variables

I have some issue with a variable created inside an if loop. Can this variable be changed to global so that it is available to the entire program, not just in the inside of a loop?

`set_point_value` is created here from an incoming request from HTML. I would like to use this variable outside the `if` loop

.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('button') == 'pass_value':
            set_point_value = request.form['temp_value']
            db.child('target_temps').push({'temp': set_point_value})
            print("Set point = " + set_point_value)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not the best idea to create variables as globals, but this is how it is done:

```py
SOME_GLOBAL = None

def foo():
    global SOME_GLOBAL
    ...
    SOME_GLOBAL = "test"
    ...

print(SOME_GLOBAL) # None
foo()
print(SOME_GLOBAL # test
```

In any case, I would recommend considering just passing the var to the right functions or using a class